# Delegation: Bulk Insert failed when executed from SSRS dataset but success from SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, bulk-insert, impersonation

I've configured delegation for SQL server engine and SSRS and it works fine.

SQL Server (2017) engine and SSRS installd on the same machine. Let's call it SqlSrv1.

What we should attain to:
User opens a report with a dataset which joins a database data and an external shared file (with sensitive data) via impersonation. If user has no access to a shared file, report should display him an empty sensitive columns.

1. When I execute `BULK INSERT` via SSMS, something like

```
BULK INSERT #t1 FROM '\\FS1\common\anyfile.txt'
```

it works fine. Computer Management shows my name (instead of sqlengine service account) in "Shared folders\Sessions" as User and SqlSrv1 as Computer.

2. Now when I execute `BULK INSERT` from SSRS report dataset against a local file (stored on SqlSrv1 `C:\anyfile.txt`) it works and ProcMon displays my name in Detail column, instead of ssrs service account.
3. At last I execute BULK INSERT from SSRS report dataset against a shared file `\\FS1\common\anyfile.txt` and I get error `Operating system error 5(Access is denied.)`, but ProcMon displays my name in Detail column as Impersonating.

There is a something strange I've located:
When I change Data Source in connection string of dataset to `FQDN`, `BULK INSERT` begones to work from SSRS. After that I change back Data Source to `NetBIOS` but `BULK INSERT` continues to work. What is going on?

All fine and dandy, but after restart SSRS service I get error `Operating system error 5(Access is denied.)` again.

When I execute the query from the step 1, ProcMon shows me the path
`\\FS1\common\\anyfile.txt` (with double slash after shared folder name! What?!!)
instead of
`\\FS1\common\anyfile.txt`

When I get error 5, ProcMon shows
`\\FS1\common\anyfile.txt` (without double slash)

But when the step 3 begones to work (after `FQDN` manipulations), OMG! The ProcMon shows me
`\\FS1\common\\anyfile.txt` (with double slash)
and after SSRS service restart I see in ProcMon
`\\FS1\common\anyfile.txt` (without double slash)
I've tryed to add double slash to `BULK INSERT`, but with no luck, SQL engine drops it (as expected).

Have you any ideas?

Comment: Are you keeping the target file in the root folder ? Try creating a subfolder and applying the appropriate permissions there

Comment: @mo64, it's just for test and example. Ofcourse I don't keep it in the root. In regards to permission for share, All domain users can read and write

Comment: This sounds like a very odd process that there's probably an easier solution for. What is your end goal that you need to `BULK INSERT` an **SSRS** dataset and a **File** together? Also a little unclear if you're saying you're trying to `BULK INSERT` **into** an SSRS dataset, **in conjunction** with one, or **from** one, as I see no mention of the **SSRS** report or dataset at all?

Comment: @J.D., My end goal is to use a secret part of data in conjunction with MDS databese and DWH, but our customer wants to to hide his secret data from not only most of employes but from developers too. MDS and likewise SSRS does not support encryption, as far as I know.
Therefore I can't see another way except shared folder containing file with a part of a secret data. This way allows to develop and to debug with any shared folder containing a sample file and use a report with another path (to real file) in production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome browser does not request a kerberos ticket with delegation flag by default.
Therefore when report was viewing via Chrome I get

> Operating system error 5(Access is denied.)

exception, because it's as if anonymous user for endpoint, while IE request a kerberos ticket with delegation flag. And a report works fine in Chrome after it was open in IE previously.

See [AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist) for Chrome

I have found the issue with `klist` utility

PS. Double or single slashes in paths has no any relevance to this issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad I asked what your end goal was. I was going to reply in a comment but it turned into too long of a response.

Your best bet is honestly to close this question and ask a new one on "best ways to implement data encryption and obfuscation across multiple databases?" with details on each type of data system you're using. There's a multitude of ways to accomplish what your customer wants with out-of-the-box features of SQL Server without rigging together a roundabout solution.

One of them is [Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/sql-server-encryption?view=sql-server-ver15) another is [Dynamic Data Masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver15), and finally understanding proper [Permissioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) in SQL Server are all standard and potential ways to hide your customer's data, even from developers.

All three of those previously mentioned plus many other features, are applicable to the databases that are utilized by the systems you mentioned (SQL Server version dependent).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I can't take advantage of your suggestion, because of MDS does not support DDM and encryption. There is no another GUI to manage data except MDS. Of course there is a few business systems in a customer infrastructure, but this report (and others) goes beyond the purposes of that systems. Developers and DBAs have admin permissions to MDS.

Comment: I understand this extended permissions is not the best practices, but I can't affect it and therefore I can't guarantee data safity to my customer. And only file storage server have one person with admin permissions and who signed a secrecy agreement. This fact led me to use "duct tape" as a shared file.

Comment: @TJS While you think you're solving the problem, even *duct tape* falls apart over time. Unless you're the highest level IT admin at the company, and you don't have a boss above you (technical or not) your solution has a lot of risk, e.g. what stops the IT Admin from undoing the file share permissions you put in place? All the solutions I mentioned above apply because **MDS** uses a regular [SQL Server database](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server_Master_Data_Services) under the hood: "*Master Data Services uses a Microsoft SQL Server database as the physical data store*".

Comment: I don't understand how can I bring MDS (WebApp, Excel Add-in) to decrypt a column with the Always encrypted option

Comment: @TJS MDS has to store that centralized data somewhere, which is a SQL Server database. You'll have to talk to your DBA, the person who setup MDS / the database, or research into where that database lives in your organization. Then you should be able to connect to it like any other SQL Server database and apply the same features as well. Hopefully this [RedGate article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/data-platform/master-data-services-basics/) helps explain the details to you. Without working at your organization, I couldn't tell you the location of your databases unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I understand how does it works. But I try to tell there is a two standard tools Microsoft provides to interact wit MDS DB - WebApp and Excel Add-In. Of course I can connect to MDS DB directly, but if I try to modify DB structure beyond the MDServise, it may cause big headache. Because MDS sould be faced unexpected field data type and service will have been crushed inevitable. Decryption is a client-side task, so Excel Add-in or WebApp should have to do that, but there is no corresponding option to use a cert, such as special tab of "Connect to server" dialog of SSMS

Comment: I belive you know what error you get if you try to insert numeric value into "Always encrypted" numeric column. The same goes for SSRS. This [article](https://www.ryanjadams.com/2020/11/always-encrypted-data-displayed-in-ssrs-with-a-gmsa/) discribes how to display encrypted data in SSRS, but it's futile undertaking if I can't manipulate encrypted data via standard MDS tools.

Comment: As you know, MDS provides entity designer (via WebUI). So what will hapend if user try to add new column to manual modified table? No joy will hapen I think.

Comment: Ultimately I can create a standalone DB anywhere and use Always encrypted, it doesn't have to be MDS. But I should provide some kind of tool to user to manipulate data, while in file share case user can use Excel to create CSV.

Comment: @TJS This is probably the last response I can afford to give on this question before this turns into an extended discussion which is not appropriate on StackExchange. Please create a new question as I mentioned earlier on, and you can gather the answers needed to your questions and assumptions to clarify your pain points. Also please read the comments of my related answer to [this StackExchange question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/284174/150011) where Microsoft's David Browne mentions that **Transparent Data Encryption** requires **no** changes to your application side. In other words...

Comment: ...the encryption process happens transparently under the hood, and doesn't impact your ability to interact with the database from your consuming applications, such as MDS, Excel, etc. So you won't have to worry about failures or special handling with inserting data, changing the schema, or consuming the data into your end applications, even MDS.