# SQL Server CLE Encryption Implementation

Tags: sql-server, encryption

We got instruction from HQ to implement encryption on our database. The reason be, should a client gets hacked, the hackers cannot access personal info such as names, phone numbers, addresses, etc.

I have done a fair bit of research and it seems that Cell Level Encryption could be the way to got but I have some questions regarding the implementation (I am a developer, not really DBA material...).

Am I correct in saying the following:

1. All data types, for the columns we want to encrypt, must be changed to varbinary
2. We have to change all our SELECT statements to include DecryptByKey for encrypted columns
3. We have to change all INSERT & UPDATE statements to include EncryptByKey for encrypted columns

Since 99% of all selects, inserts and updates in our system happen in stored procedures, how would I implement the opening and closing of the SYMMETRIC KEY? Surely, any hacker worth something, can look at the SP code to see which key was used, or just execute the SP the get the data?

Also, is there a way to determine if a column contains encrypted data? We have generic insert/update functions and these would need to know when to use EncryptByKey.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your question is heavily based on the premise that column-level encryption is the correct encryption choice. Using SQL Server Always Encrypted will solve many of these questions, though may raise new questions. Did you evaluate Always Encrypted and determine it wasn't a good fit? Or did you miss it because it's a newer feature?

Comment: @AMtwo, no I did not miss this feature. We have clients who are still on SQL 2008, with the majority on 2014. I am also concerned about  performance, that is why TDA did not look like an option.

Comment: @Johan: Always Encrypted is a different feature than TDE (and it does require a few changes in the client application).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements, I would actually recommend [**Transparent Data Encryption (TDE)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of **CLE**.

**TDE** encrypts at the database level and therefore you don't have to worry about being compromised by storing the decryption process in a stored procedure. Rather, **TDE** works on the traditional **private** and **asymmetric** key pattern to prevent access to the unencrypted data without the proper key (which you can handle authenticating outside of the database to decouple the security concerns).

It's also better in my opinion because it doesn't force you to change your data types to `VARBINARY` which almost certainly could affect the performance of your queries. Rather it keeps everything as you designed under the hood (hence **Transparent**) when you access your database.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am very concerned about performance, we already have issues at large clients. What would the impact be of TDE vs CLE? Going the TDE route, what changes would I need to make to my client app?

Comment: @Johan If you're concerned about performance then I'd carefully research into **CLE** and performance implications before implementing it, as `VARBINARY` is certainly not a performant data type to index on, or create predicates against. While I haven't personally used **CLE**, knowing how the SQL Engine works, I'd be weary of that drawback. My understanding (though again I've only looked into it in theory, haven't in practice) is your client app would have minimal changes with **TDE** as you'd only need a way to authenticate with the database via the **public key** from your app.

Comment: TDE requires no changes to the client application, but does not bring any security benefits if the client application is hacked. It helps  if the hard drive of the server is stolen (an unlikely scenario in my opinion) or the MDF/LDF files are copied by a hacker from the server.

Comment: TDE has minimal performance impact and requires no application changes.

Comment: OP mentions the goal is to protect against a client that gets "hacked." If a bad actor gains access to credentials in a way that allows connecting to the instance, TDE doesn't protect against that attack vector. TDE really only protects against stolen data files or backups or disk-level access.

Comment: @AMtwo Sure, no single security strategy will protect you against all attack vectors, but TDE is probably an applicable choice for one security measure that can be deployed (among others) for OP's goals (especially now knowing performance is a factor too). How OP manages his database credentials to connect to the database should also follow proper security protocols, to ensure additional levels of overall protection, but is probably outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on our application architecture (15 year old multi-layer COM+ where everything is done in SPs), not one of the 3 options will satisfy our requirements.

*CLE:*

- Code to open the SYMMETRIC KEY will have to be inside the SP, which will make it accessible to anybody
- It will take months to change all SPs to implement DecryptByKey/EncryptByKey and opening/closing of key

*TDE*

- Probably our best option since no client changes are required and does provide some level of protection
- Does not provide any security if hackers gain access to machine (see comments from Razvan and AMtwo)

*Always Encrypted*

- Only available with SQL Server 2016 and later (we have a lot of clients on earlier versions)
- Encryption occurs client-side via Always Encrypted enabled client driver, therefore it won't work with SPs